# how to add data to timestamp column in sql server through c# coding in vb

Tags: c#, sql

[image]
[image]

I am creating a billing system. I attached the selling form here. I need when I click the save button, to save the data to the bill table. In the bill table data type of the Bill date is timestamp.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string query = "INSERT INTO bill(bill_no,total_amount,bill_date) VALUES('"
      + txtBillNo.Text + "', '" + txtBillTotal.Text + "','" + txtBillDate.Text + "')";

  using(con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
   SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
   con.Open();
   com.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();

   MessageBox.Show("Record added successfully!", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
       MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  }
```

Comment: In sql server, `timestamp` is **not** a suitable datatype for storing dates. Use `datetime2` instead.

Comment: First make sure the database has the column set to DateTime.  Then use  a parameter in the command text.  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Question title (and vb.net tag) is misleading at least: how vb enter in the question? consider editing it

Comment: Unrelated tips: `SqlCommand` is also `IDisposable` so should be in a `using` block. Also avoid using string concatenation to construct queries or the code becomes vulnerable to SQL injection attacks: use SQL parameters. And you don't need to explicitly `Close` the connection because the implicit `Dispose` will call that for you as you exit the connection's `using` block.

Comment: P.S. It isn't clear what problem you are suffering; but using parameters might fix that as well.

Answer (score 1):

[screenshot of SSMS column properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWDh4.jpg)
Within the table on sql you could set the bill_date column to

- Allownulls `No`
- DateType `datetime`
- Default Binding `getdate()`

This will automatically add the date time to the field on successful insertion into the table.

Hope this helps?

Comment: The MSDN documentation for [datetime](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) recommends using [datetime2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx)